# weka speed up performance

Tags: ubuntu, machine-learning, weka

I am using weka CLI to process more than 200,000 datasets using different algorithms as C4.5, SVM...etc using Ubuntu . However, I have noticed that it would take more than 3 weeks to have the results!

I searched for different solutions, and one of them states to increase the memory size for Java. I have did this (as illustrated below) but it didn't enhance the performance.

```
i.e:    java -Xmx4096m  weka.classifiers.meta.MetaCost -C Cost_10.cost -W weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t comb_1.arff -x 10
```

Is there any solution that i can use to increase the performance to reduce the time for getting the results please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you are creating the models because you need them (1) or to evaluate the algorithms (2).

For 1), you may :
 - to reduce the number of classifiers you are creating
 - to reduce the complexity of the classifiers with the selection of adequate parameters (as the number of trees and the number of features used in Random Forest)
 - to implement your own optimized version of the algorithms as the Weka algorithms are slow

For 2), you may :

1. to cluster the 200 k datasets in 10 to 1000 groups (based on number and type of features, ...).
2. run your classifiers on a few selected datasets from each group
3. identify what you are interested in and confirm your hypotheses by running again your classifiers on all the datasets from limited selected groups.